# Jmeter Backend Listener Sample Result null SamplerData

Tags: java, jmeter, listener, backend

I'm getting `null` responses for my `SampleResult.getSamplerData` calls. I was under the impression I'd be receiving data which I can store in a file. We need this listener to perform other work, so the `Simple File Writer` is not sufficient.

Here's my Listener method from my Listener class (which extends `AbstractBackendListenerClient`):

```
@Override
public void handleSampleResults(List<SampleResult> list, BackendListenerContext backendListenerContext) {

    try {
        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter("C:\\projects\\sampleResults.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
        list.forEach(sampleResult -> {
            try {
                bw.write(sampleResult.getSamplerData());
                bw.newLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
        bw.close();
        fileWriter.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And here's my JMX configurations:

```
  <BackendListener guiclass="BackendListenerGui" testclass="BackendListener" testname="Some Listener" enabled="true">
    <elementProp name="arguments" elementType="Arguments" guiclass="ArgumentsPanel" testclass="Arguments" enabled="true">
      <collectionProp name="Arguments.arguments"/>
    </elementProp>
    <stringProp name="classname">com.k.jmeter.SomeBackendListener</stringProp>
  </BackendListener>
```

Comment: is this happening in distributed mode or also in standalone mode ?

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK I'm sure its a standalone. We use mvn verify to run the application locally. I really dont know specifically though

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your [SampleResult.getSamplerData()](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html#getSamplerData--) query returns null most probably it indicates a problem with your **Sampler(s)** as there is nothing wrong with your listener code (apart from possible [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition))

[image]

So take a closer look at your Sampler, it might be the case it doesn't have any data at all. You can start with a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) which will allow you to faster check the results without having to recompile/copy/run the test

[image]

In the above code `prev` stands for **prev**ious sampleresult, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) for more details